# Tests won't work with MongoMapper in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, sinatra, mongomapper

I hooked up MongoMapper with Sinatra and everything works fine except for the testing. I have Autotest with Rack Testing and Rspec installed. Whenever I run autotest, it tells me

```
/home/jason/ror/sbmongo/main.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant 
MongoMapper (NameError)
```

Here is the line of code it refers to in my `main.rb` file.

```
MongoMapper.database = 'testdb'
```

What is the problem and how could I fix this?

Comment: `require 'mongo_mapper'`?

Comment: Yep, I have that in the `spec_helper.rb` and still nothing.

Comment: Is the `spec_helper.rb` required before `main.rb` in the `main_spec.rb` file?

Comment: The first thing required in `spec_helper` is the `main.rb` file. Sorry if that's not what you were asking, your question is confusing to me.

Comment: Ok, that answers my question. The convention is to name the specs of files/classes by adding "_spec" to them, hence `main_spec.rb` will run specs for `main.rb`, and since the `spec_helper` is to be required by all the specs but not all the specs need to require all the project files, it makes sense to require the main.rb file in the main_spec.rb, not the spec_helper (but that's a separate point). Basically, you need to have required mongo_mapper before main.rb is required (or before any MongoMapper code is called in either main.rb or the specs), that's the most likely reason for the error.

Comment: @iain, ahh that's the solution. `require mongo_mapper` was after I required main.rb, etc. Post it as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order that things are called via `require` in Ruby does make a difference, as a constant declared in a library will only be visible **after** a the library has been required.

When running RSpec, it's best to put general set up code in one place - the `spec_helper.rb` file - and then in the individual specs, (for example, when specing `main.rb`) `require 'spec_helper` and *then* `require main.rb`. If each code file requires the libraries it needs in the right order, then your specs will run without a problem too. If not, it's a sign that the order of `require`s isn't quite right.